# Is there a way to make MTLTexture using only pixel data pointer without using CVPixelBuffer?

Tags: swift, graphics, metal

Currently, I copy pixel data to y, u, v plane of CVPixelBuffer, create CVMetalTexture using CVMetalTextureCache, and import and use MTLTexture.

Is there a way to make CVMetalTexture without copying pixel data to y, u, v plane of CVPixelBuffer?
Or, is there a way to create an MTLTexture using only the pixel data pointer without using CVPixelBuffer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to create an MTLTexture is:

Create an [`MTLTextureDescriptor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexturedescriptor) to describe the texture you want — its size, pixel format, quantity of mip maps, etc.

Use your texture descriptor to request a new texture from your `MTLDevice`, via [`makeTexture(descriptor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433425-newtexturewithdescriptor).

Use [`replace(region:mipmapLevel:slice:withBytes:bytesPerRow:bytesPerImage:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexture/1515679-replace) on the texture to populate the texture with data.

`CVMetalTexture` exists primarily to bridge CoreVideo data into Metal — e.g. if you want to decode a video and display it within a 3d scene. It's not intended to be useful if you're not already in the `CV` world.